# Returning params/credit card info during unsuccessful Braintree transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, braintree

When I submit a braintree transaction, and it is unsuccessful, it returns result.params that I can use.  However, due to PCI compliance reasons, it cannot return CC or CVV information.

Since it's an unsuccessful txn, the page renders the current page. I would like to auto populate the payment info, whether it's a CC or paypal transaction, so the user does not need to reenter the payment.   I think it's bad user experience.

If repopulating the payment info is not possible, could I just somehow reuse the generated payment_method_nonce and send it to braintree. Looking through the docs, I can't seem to find anything that I can use to solve this.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/reference/general/result-handling/result-objects#params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you're looking for more help with your integration, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Instead of creating a transaction with the payment method nonce, create a [payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/server/payment-method-management/create) with the nonce. This will give you a reusable token you can then use to create a transaction.

From the ["Getting Started" guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/start/create-transaction):

> ## Create a transaction
>
> Obtained from the [Braintree client SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/client), a payment method nonce can be used in any place credit card information or a payment method token is used in the Braintree [server-side client libraries](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/server).

So since you can create a payment method token from credit card params, you can also create it from a payment method nonce.

Comment: Thank you. I contacted Braintree, and the only ways to do what I want to do seem to be to create a customer in Braintree, and generate a payment token from the payment info(nonce), and use that info. I could always create my own form, or add a hidden input/jquery hack, but that does not seem secure and I want to use their payment ui with paypal integration.

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on PCI DSS before suggesting (or using) this approach. It isn't just a matter of security -- handling credit card numbers can create serious compliance burdens. https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/pci-compliance-basics-for-credit-card-security

Answer (score -1):

Simply post it to your own controller/action that is set up to [make the request](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html). From there, you can check the success of the transaction and respond accordingly. You also have full access to the params, to do with as you wish. You probably want to [keep them out of your logs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters-filtering).

Comment: With Braintree (and some other gateways) the credit card params never post to his page -- one of the advantages is you don't have to store credit card info, which comes with a whole set of headaches. So this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @agf: Thanks for your feedback, but can't you simply make a form with the requisite fields, submitting to your own controller, with a view similar to https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby_examples/blob/master/rails3_tr_checkout/app/views/payments/new.html.erb, and then post those values to Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url "by hand"? I'll admit I've not done this with Braintree specifically, but I have used a similar method for many other services, and it would appear to work well in this instance as well. If I'm way off base, I will delete this answer.

Comment: It's not that you *can't* do it, it's that you *don't want to do it*. It's bad for your server to ever see / handle credit card params, and part of the point of using a service like Braintree is to avoid that.

Comment: I upvoted your method, as a more appropriate official method. But the technique presented here can definitely improve some workflows, and can be a valuable alternative in some cases. I believe it is possible to do this as securely as the mechanism you have described... I think a bigger advantage to Braintree is that is it a great payment processor with really good developer resources. Anyway, now there are two dramatically different approaches presented to the OP that should just about cover every possible use case.

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on PCI DSS before suggesting (or using) this approach. It isn't just a matter of security -- handling credit card numbers can create serious compliance burdens.

Comment: PCI applies to ALL organizations or merchants, regardless of size or number of transactions, that accepts, TRANSMITS or stores any cardholder data. This solution does not add any additional burdens that do not exist using the solution provided by @agf. As much as I appreciate the downvote, this solution is the only one that directly addresses the original question (which was not how can I become PCI compliant).